# I can't get .addClass to work in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer-11

```
function redrawButtonToolbar() {
    //debugger;
    var buttonYears = window.availableButtonYears;

    $(".year-btn").removeClass('hidden').each(function(index) {
        var yearBtn = $(this).find('input').val();
        console.log("buttonYears: " + buttonYears + " yearBtn: " + yearBtn);

        if(yearBtn === 'all') {
            return
        }

        if(!buttonYears.indexOf(yearBtn) !== -1) {
            $(this).addClass('hidden')
            return
        }

    })

}
```

** called from another function

```
window.availableButtonYears = _.uniq(_.map(_.filter(window.data, selectionFilter), "Year"));
```

When I run debugger, I get the following values stored in window.availableButtonYears **2014, 2015, 2016**

the above code works great in Chrome but it doesn't work in IE11.

**UPDATED**
From console.log

```
buttonYears: 2014,2015,2016 yearBtn: all
buttonYears: 2014,2015,2016 yearBtn: 2017
buttonYears: 2014,2015,2016 yearBtn: 2016
buttonYears: 2014,2015,2016 yearBtn: 2015
buttonYears: 2014,2015,2016 yearBtn: 2014
```

Comment: Any errors in the console? Did you run console.log() to see what is different?

Comment: No errors or warnings in the console.

Comment: So `console.log(buttonYears);` and `console.log(yearBtn)` and `console.log(buttonYears.indexOf(yearBtn), !buttonYears.indexOf(yearBtn))` Figure out why....

Comment: updated code and produced output from console.log

Comment: You updated your code with a new bug `!buttonYears.indexOf(yearBtn) !== -1` And changing the original code to use that of one of the answers is not always the best thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your use of indexOf. It does not seem to match the usual ways of using that function, which makes me suspect that you misued it.

This code means that you check specifically if "yearBtn" is at index 0 or not:

```
if(!string.indexOf("needle"))
```

It is equivalent to this code:

```
if(string.indexOf("needle") == 0) //the string is at index 0
```

Doing this instead would mean hat you check if "yearBtn" is present in the string or not :

```
if(string.indexOf("needle") >= 0) //the string is present

if(string.indexOf("needle") < 0) //the string is not present
```

Comment: Checks to see if it is not at zero and it is a comment, not an answer. Some day you will have enough rep to comment....

Comment: Well excuse me for not researching what he's actually trying to achieve, but instead to simply tell him that he's misusing indexOf. turns out it was the problem, so I feel good about my answer.

Comment: The problem is the way you stated your answer is a comment not an answer. I am just trying to help you out make your answers better. If you worded it. `Your use of indexOf is wrong` and gave code to make it a good answer.

Comment: OK. I'll try to do better next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `indexOf` returns `-1` if it doesn't find anything. Not necessarily false.

```
    if(buttonYears.indexOf(yearBtn) !== -1) {
```

Comment: When I do this, it removed all the buttons including the ones that contained information. I was trying to only remove buttons that did not contain data.

Comment: Use debugger to step thru and see what the values are, this answer provides you with why your addClass is never called, you should be able to figure out why from here